# Regex Javascript - replace : with {}

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm looking for a generic way to replace : with {}, as I'm working with different URLs, but I will need to replace : with {} for all of them.

For example:
`users/:user_id/creditcards)`

I would like to replace `:user_id` with `{user_id}`.
How can I do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You could look for a colon and folowing letters and underscore and replace the values by taking curly brackets and the value of the group.

Because of the `'g'` flag (means global) of the regular expression it replaces all found elements.

```js
var string = 'users/:user_id/creditcards)',
    replaced = string.replace(/:([a-z_]+)/gi, '{$1}');
    
console.log(replaced);
```

Another attempt by looking for characters who are not slashs.

```js
var string = 'users/:user_id/creditcards)',
    replaced = string.replace(/:([^/]+)/g, '{$1}');
    
console.log(replaced);
```

Comment: does it replace all encounters with : ? in case there are multiple parameters in the url.

Comment: the `g` flag of the regular expression means *global*. so yes, it does.

Comment: Please post as answer so I will be able to accept it.

Answer (score 1):

if I understand the pattern you are looking for,
starts with ':' + variable name
ends just before a '/' or end of line

than I would go with:

```
const regex = /:([^\/]+)(\/|$)/gm;
const str = `:user_id/users/:user_id/creditcards/:user_id`;
const subst = `{$1}$2`;

// The substituted value will be contained in the result variable
const result = str.replace(regex, subst);
```

it catches start middle and end of pattern